# Параллельная программа на OpenMP выполняется очень медленно

Tags: c++, openmp

написал параллельную программу на OpenMP для решения системы разностных уравнений методом переменных направлений. Проблема в следующем - последовательная версия программы выполняется на сервере за 0.03 секунды, а кода запускаю на 2 и более потоках, то программа превышает лимит времени для выполнения на сервере и файл вывода, в котором выводится время выполнения программы оказывается пустой. Поэтому я даже не знаю сколько она выполняется, но до момента, пока появится пустой файл вывода проходит около 10 минут. Но по идее на 2 и более потоках она должна работать быстрее, а на деле все наоборот. В чем дело?
Вот код:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>
using namespace std;
const int n = 100;
int i00 = n / 4;
int j00 = n / 4;
//определение источника
double diraca(int x)
{
        if (x == 0)
                return 1.0;
        else
                return 0.0;
}
double max(double a, double b)
{
        if (a > b)
                return a;
        else
                return b;
}
int main()
{
        double V, U;
        U = 1.0; V = 1.0;
        double D = 0.01;
        const double h = 100.0 / double(n);
        double a1 = D / (h*h) + U / h;
        double b1 = D / (h*h) + V / h;
        double c1 = D / (h*h);
        double d1 = D / (h*h);
        double Q1 = 10.0;
        int i, j;
        double e1 = 2.0*D / (h*h) + U / h + 2.0*D / (h*h) + V / h;
        double e2 = a1 + c1;
        double e3 = b1 + d1;
        double tau = 0.99;


        double f1[n + 1][n + 1];
        //решение на n-шаге
        double C0[n + 1][n + 1];
        //решение на (n+1/2)-шаге
        double C1[n + 1][n + 1];
        //решение на (n+1)-шаге
        double C2[n + 1][n + 1];
        //прогоночные коэфф.-ты
        double P[n + 1], Q[n + 1];
        //начальные условия распределения примеси
        for (i = 0; i < n + 1; i++)
                for (j = 0; j < n + 1; j++) {
                        f1[i][j] = Q1 * diraca(i - i00) * diraca(j - j00);
                        C2[i][j] = 0.0;
                        C1[i][j] = 0.0;
                        C0[i][j] = 0.0;
                }

        double error = 1.0;
        double t=omp_get_wtime();
        while (error > 1e-7)
        {

                #pragma omp parallel for private(i,j) shared(C0)
                for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                                C0[i][j] = C2[i][j];

                double a, b, c, d[n + 1];


                //прогонка по столбцам
                #pragma omp parallel for private(j) shared(C1)
                for (j = 1; j < n; j++)
                {
                        a = -a1; b = -(1 / tau + e2); c = -c1;
                        i = 1;
                        d[1] = d1 * C0[i][j + 1] + (1 / tau - e3)*C0[i][j] + f1[i][j];
                        i = n-1;
                        d[n - 1] = b1 * C0[i][j-1] +  (1 / tau - e3)*C0[i][j] + f1[i][j];
                        for (i = 2; i < n-1; i++)
                                d[i] = b1 * C0[i][j - 1] + d1 * C0[i][j + 1] + (1 / tau - e3)*C0[i][j] + f1[i][j];
                        P[1] = c / b;
                        Q[1] = -d[1] / b;
                        for (i = 2; i < n; i++)
                        {
                                P[i] = c / (-a * P[i - 1] + b);
                                Q[i] = (-d[i] + a * Q[i - 1]) / (-a * P[i - 1] + b);
                        }
                        C1[n - 1][j] = (d[n - 1] - Q[n - 1] * a) / (-b + P[n - 1] * a);
                        for (i = n - 2; i >= 1; i--)
                        {
                                C1[i][j] = P[i] * C1[i + 1][j] + Q[i];
                        }
                }


                //граничные условия шаг (n+1/2)
                #pragma omp parallel for private(i) shared(C1)
                for (i = 0; i < n + 1; i++)
                        C1[n][i] = C0[n - 1][i];
                #pragma omp parallel for private(i) shared(C1)
                for (i = 0; i < n + 1; i++)
                        C1[i][n] = C0[i][n - 1];
                #pragma omp parallel for private(i) shared(C1)
                for (i = 0; i < n + 1; i++)
                        C1[0][i] = 0.0;
                #pragma omp parallel for private(i) shared(C1)
                for (i = 0; i < n + 1; i++)
                        C1[i][0] = 0.0;


                //прогонка по строкам
                #pragma omp parallel for private(i) shared(C2)
                for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
                {
                        a = -b1; b = -(1 / tau + e3); c = -d1;
                        j = 1;
                        d[1] = C1[i+1][j] - (1 / tau - e2)*C1[i][j] + f1[i][j];
                        j = n-1;
                        d[n - 1] = a1 * C1[i - 1][j] - (1 / tau - e2)*C1[i][j] + f1[i][j];
                        for (j = 2; j < n-1; j++)
                                d[j] = a1 * C1[i - 1][j] + c1 * C1[i + 1][j] - (1 / tau - e2)*C1[i][j] + f1[i][j];
                        P[1] = c / b;
                        Q[1] = -d[1] / b;
                        for (j = 2; j < n; j++)
                        {
                                P[j] = c / (-a * P[j - 1] + b);
                                Q[j] = (-d[j] + a * Q[j - 1]) / (-a * P[j - 1] + b);
                        }
                        C2[i][n - 1] = (d[n - 1] - Q[n - 1] * a) / (-b + P[n - 1] * a);
                        for (j = n - 2; j >= 1; j--)
                        {
                                C2[i][j] = P[j] * C2[i][j + 1] + Q[j];
                        }
                }



                //граничные условия шаг (n+1)
                #pragma omp parallel for private(i) shared(C2)
                for (i = 0; i < n + 1; i++)
                        C2[n][i] = C1[n - 1][i];
                #pragma omp parallel for private(i) shared(C2)
                for (i = 0; i < n + 1; i++)
                        C2[i][n] = C1[i][n - 1];
                #pragma omp parallel for private(i) shared(C2)
                for (i = 0; i < n + 1; i++)
                        C2[0][i] = 0.0;
                #pragma omp parallel for private(i) shared(C2)
                for (i = 0; i < n + 1; i++)
                        C2[i][0] = 0.0;



                error = 0.0;
                #pragma omp parallel for private(i,j) reduction(+:error)
                for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
                        for (j = 1; j < n; j++)
                                error += pow(fabs(C2[i][j] - C0[i][j]), 2);
                error = pow(error / (n*n), 0.5);


        }
        t=omp_get_wtime()-t;
        FILE *f;
        f=fopen("result.txt","w");
        for(i=1;i<n;i++)
            for(j=1;j<n;j++)
                fprintf(f,"%i %i %lf\n",i,j,C2[i][j]);
        fclose(f);     
        printf("Time=%lf\n",t);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Алгоритм последовательный. Ваши попытки распараллелить приводят к неразберихе данных.

Comment: Как тогда лучше распараллелить?

Comment: Распараллелить этот код? - никак. Нужно переписывать весь алгоритм. Проблемы, которые не дают делать этот код параллельным или делают бессмысленным использование OpenMP: 1. У Вас есть явная зависимость данных от соседних итераций (в одной итерации используете j+1, j, j-1); 2. Время выполнения одной итерации цикла, который Вы пытаетесь параллелить на порядок (-ки) меньше времени запуска потоков; 3. Не нужно пытаться параллелить заведомо короткие циклы (которые, к тому же, можно было просто объединить); 4. Имеет смысл параллелить внешний цикл, но он у Вас `while` и его так просто не выйдет...

Comment: 5. В циклах с `omp` у Вас используется присвоение значений каким-то массивам (d, P, Q), используете переменные (a,b,c,i и т.п.), которым Вы не задали политики - это все ведет к гонке данных и полностью неверным результатам работы программы.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, я не знаю как по-другому написать алгоритм вычислений. Вот какие исправления я внес, но все равно не работает как надо

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>
using namespace std;
const int n = 100;
int i00 = n / 4;
int j00 = n / 4;
//определение источника
double diraca(int x)
{
    if (x == 0)
        return 1.0;
    else
        return 0.0;
}
double max(double a, double b)
{
    if (a > b)
        return a;
    else
        return b;
}
int main()
{
    double V, U;
    U = 1.0; V = 1.0;
    double D = 0.01;
    const double h = 100.0 / double(n);
    double a1 = D / (h*h) + U / h;
    double b1 = D / (h*h) + V / h;
    double c1 = D / (h*h);
    double d1 = D / (h*h);
    double Q1 = 10.0;
    int i, j;
    double e1 = 2.0*D / (h*h) + U / h + 2.0*D / (h*h) + V / h;
    double e2 = a1 + c1;
    double e3 = b1 + d1;
    double tau = 0.9;


    double f1[n + 1][n + 1];
    //решение на n-шаге
    double C0[n + 1][n + 1];
    //решение на (n+1/2)-шаге
    double C1[n + 1][n + 1];
    //решение на (n+1)-шаге
    double C2[n + 1][n + 1];
    //прогоночные коэфф.-ты
    double P[n + 1], Q[n + 1];
    //начальные условия распределения примеси
    for (i = 0; i < n + 1; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n + 1; j++) 
        {
            f1[i][j] = Q1 * diraca(i - i00) * diraca(j - j00);
            C2[i][j] = 0.0;
            C1[i][j] = 0.0;
            C0[i][j] = 0.0;
        }

    double error = 1.0;
    double t=omp_get_wtime();
    while (error > 1e-7)
    {

        #pragma omp parallel for private(i,j) shared(C0,C2)
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                C0[i][j] = C2[i][j];

        double a, b, c, d[n + 1];


        //граничные условия шаг (n+1/2)
        #pragma omp parallel for private(i) shared(C0,C1)
        for (i = 0; i < n+1; i++)
        { 
          C1[n][i] = C0[n - 1][i];
          C1[i][n] = C0[i][n - 1];
          C1[0][i] = 0.0;
          C1[i][0] = 0.0;
        }


        //прогонка по столбцам
        #pragma omp parallel for private(j) shared(a,b,c,i,d,C0,P,Q,C1)
        for (j = 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            a = -a1; b = -(1 / tau + e2); c = -c1;
            i = 1;
            d[1] = d1 * C0[i][j + 1] + (1 / tau - e3)*C0[i][j] + f1[i][j];
            i = n-1;
            d[n - 1] = b1 * C0[i][j-1] +  (1 / tau - e3)*C0[i][j] + f1[i][j];
            for (i = 2; i < n-1; i++)
                d[i] = b1 * C0[i][j - 1] + d1 * C0[i][j + 1] + (1 / tau - e3)*C0[i][j] + f1[i][j];
            P[1] = c / b;
            Q[1] = -d[1] / b;
            for (i = 2; i < n; i++)
            {
                P[i] = c / (-a * P[i - 1] + b);
                Q[i] = (-d[i] + a * Q[i - 1]) / (-a * P[i - 1] + b);
            }
            C1[n - 1][j] = (d[n - 1] - Q[n - 1] * a) / (-b + P[n - 1] * a);
            for (i = n - 2; i >= 1; i--)
            {
                C1[i][j] = P[i] * C1[i + 1][j] + Q[i];
            }
        }


        //граничные условия шаг (n+2)
        #pragma omp parallel for private(i) shared(C1,C2)
        for (i = 0; i < n+1; i++)
        { C2[n][i] = C1[n - 1][i];
          C2[i][n] = C1[i][n - 1];
          C2[0][i] = 0.0;
          C2[i][0] = 0.0;
            }



        //прогонка по строкам
        #pragma omp parallel for private(i) shared(a,b,c,j,d,C1,P,Q,C2)
        for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            a = -b1; b = -(1 / tau + e3); c = -d1;
            j = 1;
            d[1] = C1[i+1][j] - (1 / tau - e2)*C1[i][j] + f1[i][j];
            j = n-1;
            d[n - 1] = a1 * C1[i - 1][j] - (1 / tau - e2)*C1[i][j] + f1[i][j]; 
            for (j = 2; j < n-1; j++)
                d[j] = a1 * C1[i - 1][j] + c1 * C1[i + 1][j] - (1 / tau - e2)*C1[i][j] + f1[i][j];
            P[1] = c / b;
            Q[1] = -d[1] / b;
            for (j = 2; j < n; j++)
            {
                P[j] = c / (-a * P[j - 1] + b);
                Q[j] = (-d[j] + a * Q[j - 1]) / (-a * P[j - 1] + b);
            }
            C2[i][n - 1] = (d[n - 1] - Q[n - 1] * a) / (-b + P[n - 1] * a);
            for (j = n - 2; j >= 1; j--)
            {
                C2[i][j] = P[j] * C2[i][j + 1] + Q[j];
            }
        }


        error = 0.0;
        #pragma omp parallel for private(i,j) reduction(+:error)
        for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
            for (j = 1; j < n; j++)
                error += pow(fabs(C2[i][j] - C0[i][j]), 2);
        error = pow(error / (n*n), 0.5);


    }
    t=omp_get_wtime()-t;
    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("result.txt","w");
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
        for(j=1;j<n;j++)
            fprintf(f,"%i %i %lf\n",i,j,C2[i][j]);
    fclose(f);  
    printf("Time=%lf\n",t);
    return 0;
}
```